# Number of tables for a parameter form

Tags: java, database, database-design

I need to design a parameter form. I have a form which will contain a list of competencies. The user will need to rate each competency. 
Example of a form where user will rate:

```
Competency 1  - Choose rating from 0-7
Competency 2 -  Choose rating from 0-7
Competency 3 - Choose rating from 0-7
```

The rating of 0-7 is a radio button.

I want a parameter form to keep this rating, and if tomorrow the user wants to add a new rating like 8, he/she can do it from the form.

This will add a new radio button automatically on the form design.

I want to know how many tables will I need to design the parameter form? Two tables or One table?

(Note that I have about 10 parameter form to design- Can i use same table or each parameter form have its own table)

Which one is the best practice?

Comment: Each parameter has 3 competencies???

Comment: No more than. unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. But you can use something like this:

```
Competences
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 - competence_id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT
 - competence_title VARCHAR
 - competence_attr_1 ANYTYPE

Votes
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 - vote_id INT NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT
 - item_id INT -- Reference to an item, for which vote is done
 - competence_id -- Reference to competence
 - rating INT -- Rating mark
```

With this you will be able to add unlimited number of competences and use any rating on them.